# Same data is returned from cache for every consecutive ajax calls angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs, ajax, flask

I am making consecutive ajax call to my Flask application. The function in flask returns me different data for every ajax call until JSON is empty. I have coded my JS side to deal with the above concept but shom how for every ajax call the data return is what I received for my first ajax call.

Please find code below:-

```
 $http.post('/py/commandSend',{'sourceIP':'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx','commandDest':commandDest}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                requestId = data.requestId;
                console.log(requestId);
                do{
                    console.log('Request ID sent')
                    $http.post('/py/recvData',{'requestId':requestId}).
                        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log('Data after request ID')
                            console.log(data.output);
                        }).
                        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log(status);
                        });
                }while(data.output != "");
                //}while(false);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(status);
            });
        };
```

How do I make every call asynchronous, so that returning data is not from cache but from actual server.

I have also attached my Flask python code for more clarification.

```
@app.route("/py/commandSend", methods=['POST'])
def commandSend():
    data = request.json
    commandJson = json.dumps(data)
    sockSend = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sockSend.connect(('localhost', 55561))
    sockSend.send(commandJson)
    receivedData = sockSend.recv(1024)
    sockSend.close()
    resvData = Response(receivedData, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resvData


def sock():
    sockRec = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sockRec.connect(('localhost', 55561))
    return sockRec

@app.route("/py/recvData", methods=['POST'])
def recvData():
    requestId = request.json
    sentRequest = json.dumps(requestId)
    sockRecv = sock()
    time.sleep(10)
    send = sockRecv.send(sentRequest)
    recdData = sockRecv.recv(4096)
    print(recdData)
    commandData = Response(recdData, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return commandData
```

Any help would be appreciated.